# How to download large files via spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

I know how to download file in spring boot, but that require to load the whole into memory, then how to handle that if it is large file ?

Comment: Can you provide more details please ? Spring Boot is merely the application building layer. Download would be managed by either WebFlux or Web MVC (or even other product like Spring integration). Which of these technologies do you use / want an answer for ? And are you the client requesting download, or the controller serving it ?

Comment: Is this not what you would be looking for? https://www.baeldung.com/spring-resttemplate-download-large-file